# How to restart a daemondo controlled process?

Tags: process

How can I restart a daemondo controlled process with other options on my MAC (OS-X 10.4)? I changed /opt/local/etc/LaunchDaemons/org.macports.gearman/org.macports.gearman.plist and killed the gearman process. Daemondo restarted it but with the same options. How do I tell daemond to re-read the configuration and to restart a process (or all processes) with that new cenfiguration?